# How to update color on clientside_callback in plotly dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js

I am trying to create an app in dash that would use default plotly color palette for Piechart. However default palette for plotly.js is different from py version, so I am trying to edit this.
But the argument I pass into marker seems not to make any change whatsoever.
My current code is:
**EDIT: This code actually works, but by the default, plotly.js starts coloring from the smallest value passed(I think). When I passed sorted values, it works exactly the same**

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('pie-store', 'data'),
    Input('key_input', 'value')
)
def update_store_data(key):
    accs, counts = zip(*crud.key_account_counts(db, key))
    return [{
        'values': counts,
        'labels': accs,
        'names': accs,
        'type': 'pie',
        'marker':{
            'colors' : plotly.colors.DEFAULT_PLOTLY_COLORS
        },
    }]


app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(data) {
        return {
            'data': data,
        }
    }
    """,
    Output('clientside-pie', 'figure'),
    Input('pie-store', 'data'),
)
```

Comment: What happens if you use the Python callback to update the chart instead of the clientside one?

Comment: @coralvanda I dont understand what you mean :(
I would not need to update colors with callback in python, I would do it while creating graph (pass it in parameters), so I dont know how to do it.
But while creating the graph clientside, I have to pass them in some other way (afaik).

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the clientside callback? If you just use a normal callback, then I think you would have no problem, right?